# Not getting any response from url when using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to parse the API.

I am using the given URL as

https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

and I generated POJO classes.

```
public class MyPojo {
    private List<Contacts> contacts;

    public List<Contacts> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(List<Contacts> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [contacts = " + contacts + "]";
    }
}
```

***Contacts:***

```
public class Contacts
{
    private String id;

    private Phone phone;

    private String address;

    private String email;

    private String name;

    private String gender;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Phone getPhone ()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone (Phone phone)
    {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress ()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress (String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail ()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail (String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender ()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender (String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", phone = "+phone+", address = "+address+", email = "+email+", name = "+name+", gender = "+gender+"]";
    }
}
```

Then in interface, I added,

```
 public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/contacts")
    Call<MyPojo> getJSON();

}
```

Then in MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.androidhive.info")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        final ApiInterface request = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<MyPojo> call = request.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyPojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyPojo> call, Response<MyPojo> response) {
                Log.e("response", response.errorBody().toString());
                MyPojo pojo = response.body();
                List<Contacts> contactses = pojo.getContacts();
                for (int i = 0; i < contactses.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("contacsses", contactses.get(i).getAddress());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, contactses.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyPojo> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        });
       }
      }
```

I am getting a failure as Toast message.

I am clueless where I am doing a mistake. Kindly correct my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: use @GET("contacts") instead of  @GET("/contacts")

Comment: Please add code snippet of API client you have intialized

Comment: unable to resolve host. No host associated with given name

Comment: this error is due to invalid url. Please check your base url.

Comment: https://api.androidhive.info -> this is the base url which i added. @SamirBhatt and in @GET(/contacts) i used in interface..  you can check the url.. https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

Comment: @kamalverma still same error. unable to resolve host.

Comment: just for confirmation, did you add internet permission?

Comment: Omg. Yes I forgot that. Thanks. @SamirBhatt yes now it's working..

Comment: That's ok. It happens sometimes. :D

Comment: :D True @SamirBhatt